# How can OpenDaylight Helium support openflow 1.3

Tags: opendaylight

I have problem whether OpenDaylight helium can support openflow 1.3 protocols.If yes,how can I configure  or enable OpenDaylight helium to support openflow 1.3 protocols?

Answer (score 1):

OpenDaylight Helium supports openflow 1.3 by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the pre-built Helium release, when u do /bin/karaf to run the controller, add the flag -of13 and you will have your controller running openflow v1.3.